# big query label in load job using bq_hook insert_job

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have python script loading the data from csv to big query table using big query hook insert_job which works fine, however I would like to add label in configuration to identify the job in region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT. The issue is the label is not getting populated in information schema, any advice what could be incorrect with below config?

```
job_configuration = {
            "load": {
                "destinationTable": {
                    "project_id": PROJECT_NAME,
                    "datasetId": GCP_DATASET_NAME,
                    "tableId": table_name,
                },
                "sourceUris": [f"gs://{BUCKET}/{file_name}"],
                "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                "allowJaggedRows": True,
                "allowQuotedNewlines": True,
                "labels": { "airflow_dag": "load_job" },
            }
        }
try:
            bq_hook.insert_job(
                configuration=job_configuration,
                project_id=PROJECT_NAME,
            )
```

Composer version:2.0.25 and Airflow version:2.2.5

The label Key & label value columns of information are empty and would like to see the label key with "airflow_dag" and label value with "load_job"

Appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add labels on your job so it will appear when running queries on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` you need to remove key `"labels": { "airflow_dag": "load_job" }` inside `"load"`. See [Job configuration reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfiguration). Your updated job_configuration should look like this:

```json
job_configuration = {
            "load": {
                "destinationTable": {
                    "project_id": PROJECT_NAME,
                    "datasetId": GCP_DATASET_NAME,
                    "tableId": table_name,
                },
                "sourceUris": [f"gs://{BUCKET}/{file_name}"],
                "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                "allowJaggedRows": True,
                "allowQuotedNewlines": True,
                "autodetect": True,
            },
            "labels": { "airflow_dag": "load_job" } # move out of key "load"
        }
```

Tested job_configuration using sample codb below:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash,python
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery import BigQueryHook

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

PROJECT_NAME = "project-name"
GCP_DATASET_NAME = "dataset-name"
table_name = "table_name"
BUCKET = "bucket-name"
file_name = "data.csv"

job_configuration = {
            "load": {
                "destinationTable": {
                    "project_id": PROJECT_NAME,
                    "datasetId": GCP_DATASET_NAME,
                    "tableId": table_name,
                },
                "sourceUris": [f"gs://{BUCKET}/{file_name}"],
                "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                "allowJaggedRows": True,
                "allowQuotedNewlines": True,
                "autodetect": True,
            },
            "labels": { "airflow_dag": "load_job" } # move out of key "load"
        }


with models.DAG(
        'add_job_bq_label',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    def insert_job():
        hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
        hook.insert_job(
                configuration=job_configuration,
                project_id=PROJECT_NAME,
            )

    insert_data = python.PythonOperator(
        task_id='insert_data',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=insert_job,
    )

    insert_data
```

Airflow logs:

[image]

When querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT:

```sql
select * from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
where job_id LIKE "airflow%"
order by creation_time desc
```

[image]